# Is it possible to have a mapping with a hash as key?

Tags: solidity, mapping, hash

Is it possible to have a `mapping` in Solidity with a `hash` as key?

For example:

`mapping (hash => uint) hashToInt;`

If not, is there any way to group some information and put it as a key of a `mapping`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `hash` was an old type that's been replaced with `bytes32`.  You can call `keccak256(data1, data2, ...)` and use that as a key.

[Prior discussion on `hash`](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/451).