# Enum as key in mapping now allowed?

Tags: solidity

I read that enums were not allowed as keys in mappings, but when I just tried it it is working on remix.ethereum.org. Was it allowed in more recent Solidity versions?

The use-case I am using enum as key for is to encode tokens a bit differently, for a contract with multiple tokens. So it really makes that easier to read with enum Token as the key.

```
enum Token { TokenName1, TokenName2, TokenName3, TokenName4 }

mapping (Token => mapping (address => uint)) balanceOf;
mapping (Token => mapping (address => mapping (address => uint))) public allowed;
```

Comment: So what kind of answer exactly are you hoping to get here? It's either a 'yes' or a 'no', and all you really need to do in order to find out is try... which you already have!

Comment: Anyone could go into as much detail as they like, "yes it was made possible then and then, not possible to begin with for reason this or that, etc". As far as I knew, IDE could have an error and it is still not formally possible. But I Googled a bit more now and this is a reference to that enum as keys were now allowed. https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/1409. A lot of sources said it wasn't possible, like the docs here, https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/types.html, this question here as good a way as any to communicate that enums are now allowed as keys. Whatever people want.

Comment: "Was it allowed in more recent Solidity versions?" "Yes it was added 6 months ago in v. this or that" for example. Whatever anyone wants. Or the question can be ignored and there is the downvote mechanism to help with that.

Comment: I don't think there's any reason to downvote it because there's nothing wrong with it per se. What I meant to say was that other than a preliminary research (which you seemed to have already done), there was nothing left to add on top of that.

Comment: I'm not a computer scientist so my ability to reason around if the IDE could have been wrong, etc, is probably less than yours. I guess if it runs in Remix, it means the code is being compiled, which means it is able to interpret the enum as a key and that it would not have worked before (why enums were not allowed to begin with. ) And that that is proof and answers my question.

Comment: Seems to start working on 0.6.3, not working on 0.6.2 in Remix.

Comment: Looks like it was added then, february this year,
https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/commit/589d59b55ceff8172d5a3d4a286e1b1e06ab3c7e

Comment: Sounds like you have the full answer in great details. You may as well add it here as an answer to your own question, for future reference.

Comment: Wow, 9 seconds. The fastest response in the history of this website.

Comment: I didn't have the answers when I asked the question, nor was I really looking for a lecture in how to search information :) Just wondered if it had been added. I've already added an answer, if anyone else ever wants it for future reference. But, someone else could have answered too, kind of the point (obviously all information can always be accessed by yourself if you invest enough resources, like, if you had an infinitely large brain you can access anything in a nano second.. ) https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/87607/63783

Comment: (I'm just writing a simple contract. There's so much of the underlying computer science to it that I'd like to learn more about, but, since there is infinite information in the world also have to prioritize. Usually to build technical expertise starting in other direction can be better, but, in this case I learnt only to build the coordination system I wanted to build. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enum as keys in a mapping were added in Solidity v. 0.6.3, released February 18 2020. This document seems to cover the history of Solidity language, https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/develop/Changelog.md, scroll to 0.6.3.